# Simulating from the beta distribution with different parameters (from matrix) efficiently?

Tags: r, performance, simulation

I have a matrix `A` which contains the alpha parameters for my beta distributions and `A^2` contains the beta parameters. I want to get a matrix `C` which contains simulations from the beta distribution, with C[i,j] being a simulation from `Beta(A[i,j], A[i,j]^2)` etc.

I've tried `rbeta(1,A,A^2)` but this only gives a simulation for the first element.

So I created the function

```
Beta<-function(x){
rbeta(1, x, x^2)  
}
```

then used the apply function, like so

```
C<-apply(A,c(1,2), Beta)
```

Which works. The only problem is A is `100 x 100000` and my computer struggles to compute `C`. Does anyone know a quicker way of performing such a task?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. `rbeta(n,a,b)` returns a vector containing n random samples from a beta distribution with parameters a and b. So is each element of `C` in your question a vector of length n, or is it a scalar??

Comment: Each element of C should be a scalar (i.e. n=1).

Comment: So you're drawing a single sample from each of 100 million beta distributions. Are all 100MM values in `A` different?

Comment: Yes all values of A are different and a single sample from each Beta distribution is needed. Just noticed the matrix A is 100 x 100000 so there is 10 million and not 100 million beta distributions. (I'll correct that in the question.)

Answer (score 0):

You can create the whole matrix with one command. You don't need `apply` here.

```
C <- matrix(rbeta(length(A), A, A^2), dim(A))
```

This should be considerably faster, though I didn't test it.